# Does an odd number always return floor when divided with a remainder?

Tags: c++

Can I be sure that an odd number in C++ should always return floor of the result when divided in such a way that there is a remainder or are there any exceptions to this? I mean:

```
int x = 5;
x = x/2;
cout<<x;      //2
```

Comment: yes.be sure. but why? ans standard says so in 5.6.4

Comment: If the numerator is negative then the results get hinky.

Comment: By 'floor' do you mean [std::floor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor)?

Comment: @Slavik81: He does not.

Comment: @brianbeuning - not any more. C11 and C++11 changed this.

Answer (score 5):

yes. you can be sure of that in c++

**ISO/IEC N3485**(working draft) says in 5.6.4

```
The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields 
the remainder from the division of the ﬁrst expression by the second.
   If the second  operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undeﬁned. 
For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any 
fractional part discarded;81 if the quotient a/b is representable in the type 
of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a; otherwise, the behavior of both 
a/b and a%b is undeﬁned.
```

Comment: well its free,this draft :-)

Comment: That's because it's not a language standard. In this case, of course, the numbering and text are the same.

Comment: yes will buy one and post from that hence forth. is there a major difference by the way?

Comment: Ah, N3485 is in fact the _current_ working draft, from October, i.e. pre-pre-pre-C++14. See how it's not immediately clear, unless you quote an actual standard? :)

Comment: oh thanks. quite a lot of differences there. have to be more careful henceforth. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What does "algebraic quotient" mean?

Comment: "**algebraic quotient**" is nothing but the rules defined in algebra for division yielding quotient and remainder, which is nothing but `(numerator - remainder)/denominator`(all elements are whole numbers). this is our everyday division.

Answer (score 2):

Integer division is handled as a floor operation in C/C++.

You get `2` in the above example since the real answer `2.5` can't be represented.

[Some more verbose answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; division between integers is *always* integral division in C++:

> `[C++11 5.6/4]:` The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined. **For integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;** if the
>   quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`.